# How exactly do I write a callback function to change a global variable inside AJAX for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, so I look around a lot of answers and none of them seems helpful in what I want to achieve.  Say I have the following code:

```
var n = 0;
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        n = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        somefunction(n);
    }
});

console.log(n) // n would obviously be 0 again
```

I had done it by making it synchronous using `async:false`, but from what I read, it's bad for the user experience as it freezes up the browser as it waits for result. how exactly do I implement the callback function in the above case to allow global variable `n` to be modified after ajax call?

Comment: It depends how you want to use the global variable n when it is updated. Can you please describe what you use n for and how you will eventually display it to the user?

Comment: long story short, I am making a music quiz web app and I have a long list of object array of songs and their urls. Ajax call is simply to retrieve the content from a song's url. since I want to randomize `n` to get a random song and then after the ajax call is finished, I can check to see if my selection of song matches with that of random. Here is what the problem is, I cannot have the modified `n` because it wouldn't be modified in the first place because of nature of ajax.

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: `how exactly do I implement the callback function in the above case to allow global variable n to be modified after ajax call?`. Well, in your example, `n` is modified after the call, but you output it before it is modified :)

Comment: true, I goofed. I meant to ask how do I output it after the call by using callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async functions are executed in a different thread (non-blocking) thus the callback will be called past your next instruction:

```
console.log(n);
```

`n` is set after the callback (success function) is called but the log is before the async function is done. An easy solution is to wrap your code in a function and call it after jQuery calls success function. Note that you won't need to reference the global variable as it will be set outside of the jQuery scope and accessible to `operation_x` function scope.

```
var n = 0;
function operation_x(){
    console.log(n); // n is set to random value
}
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        n = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        somefunction(n);
        operation_x();
    }
});
console.log(n); // n is 0
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use JavaScript local storage:

```
 $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        n = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        somefunction(n);
localStorage.setItem("n", 100)
    }
});

var n;
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage.
    n = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Comment: What has `localStorage` to do with this? He didn't ask for persistency.